# Google Tag Manager push event to Google analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

When I used just Google anylytics I simply pushed event like this:

```
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Category', 'Action', 'Opt Label');
```

So now I switched to Google Tag Manager. I added new tag Google analytics and selected Universal Analytics. I also inserted Google Tag Manager code to my page. I read that from now I can push events like this:

```
dataLayer.push({
    'event': 'GAevent',
    'eventCategory': 'print',
    'eventAction': 'print_bottom',
    'eventLabel': 'documentname'
});
```

But this doesn't work, event is not displayed inside Google Analytics. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found out that you can not send event to google analytics with GTM without making some extra settings inside GMT. [This](https://www.vanpattenmedia.com/2014/google-analytics-tag-manager-events) is a great tutorial about it.